# Update random top 50 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update 50 rows in my table to the current date.
I know how to select 50 random results but I don't know how to update them.

This is what I have for the Select code:

```
SELECT TOP 50[ID]
      ,[Message]
      ,[Date]
      ,[Type]
      ,[Username]
FROM [database].[dbo].[dbTable]
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

If i'm correct, this will get the 50 random rows.

first I just updated the first 50 but I want to get some random values out of my database.

```
update top(50) dbTable
set date=getdate()
```

I don't want to mess up the database because I don't have access to a back up today.

If there is something unclear or anything please ask me!

Comment: Since tables are inherently *not* ordered, your `update top(50)` query is updating an undefined set of 50 rows. It's not updating the "first" 50 rows because there's no such thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE [database].[dbo].[dbTable] Set [Date] = GetDate() where [ID] IN
(
    SELECT TOP 50 [ID] FROM [database].[dbo].[dbTable] ORDER BY NEWID()
)
```

**Or** else:

```
WITH    q AS
        (
         SELECT TOP 50[ID]
              ,[Message]
              ,[Date]
              ,[Type]
              ,[Username]
         FROM [database].[dbo].[dbTable]
         ORDER BY NEWID()
        )
UPDATE  q
SET     [Date] = GetDate()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
update [dbo].[dbTable] set date=getdate() where Id in
(
    select top 50 id from dbo.dbTable order by NEWID()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`TOP 50` alone isn't going to get you random rows. There's a way to get random rows in sql-server. You can combine it with an `UPDATE` query.

Random rows:

```
SELECT TOP 50 ID FROM [database].[dbo].[dbTable] ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Applied to an `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE [database].[dbo].[dbTable]
SET Date = GETDATE()
WHERE ID IN( SELECT TOP 50 ID FROM [database].[dbo].[dbTable] ORDER BY NEWID() );
```